# Pydantic: allow mutation, forbid to change types

Tags: python, types, pydantic

Is there any way to forbid changing types of mutated Pydantic models? For example,

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class AppConfig(BaseModel):

    class Config:
        allow_mutation = True
    
    a: int = 33
    b: float = 22.0
```

I want to be able to change the fields, like:

```
config = AppConfig()
config.a = 44
```

But I want to forbid changing the fields' types, like:

```
config.a = '44'
<Some error message here>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One key thing about Pydantic that is important to understand is that it will try to *coerce* to the type you've annotated. E.g. it will try calling `int` on whatever input you give for `a`. If you *don't* want that behavior, use [strict types](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#strict-types):

```
In [1]: from pydantic import BaseModel, StrictInt, StrictFloat
   ...:
   ...: class AppConfig(BaseModel):
   ...:
   ...:     class Config:
   ...:         allow_mutation = True
   ...:
   ...:     a: StrictInt = 33
   ...:     b: StrictFloat = 22.0
   ...:

In [2]: AppConfig(a=42, b=0.0)
Out[2]: AppConfig(a=42, b=0.0)

In [3]: AppConfig(a='42', b=0.0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValidationError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-702f4ffeef8d> in <module>
----> 1 AppConfig(a='42', b=0.0)

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/wrangle/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pydantic/main.cpython-37m-darwin.so in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__()

ValidationError: 1 validation error for AppConfig
a
  value is not a valid integer (type=type_error.integer)
```

Additionally, by default pydantic won't perform validation on assignment to attributes, to change that behavior you need to set `validate_assignment` in your `Config`, so you need:

```
In [1]: from pydantic import BaseModel, StrictInt, StrictFloat
   ...:
   ...: class AppConfig(BaseModel):
   ...:
   ...:     class Config:
   ...:         allow_mutation = True
   ...:         validate_assignment = True
   ...:
   ...:     a: StrictInt = 33
   ...:     b: StrictFloat = 22.0
   ...:

In [2]: config = AppConfig()

In [3]: config
Out[3]: AppConfig(a=33, b=22.0)

In [4]: config.a = '42'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValidationError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-39b2a238b39e> in <module>
----> 1 config.a = '42'

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/wrangle/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pydantic/main.cpython-37m-darwin.so in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__setattr__()

ValidationError: 1 validation error for AppConfig
a
  value is not a valid integer (type=type_error.integer)
```